# Pandas: Calculate end-day product volumes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Am trying to calculate the volume at the end of each day for each product-buyer from this table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [pd.datetime(2020,1,1), pd.datetime(2020,1,2), pd.datetime(2020,1,3), pd.datetime(2020,1,4), pd.datetime(2020,1,5)], 'Product':['Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread', 'Water'],'Buyer': ['John', 'Mat', 'John', 'Bill', 'John'], 'Seller': ['Mat', 'John', 'Bill', 'John', 'Bill'], 'Volume':[1000,2000,3000,2000,1000]})

df
         day Product Buyer Seller  Volume
0 2020-01-01   Bread  John    Mat    1000
1 2020-01-02   Bread   Mat   John    2000
2 2020-01-03   Bread  John   Bill    3000
3 2020-01-04   Bread  Bill   John    2000
4 2020-01-05   Water  John   Bill    1000

df_expected

Out[61]: 
         day Product Buyer  Volume
0 2020-01-01   Bread  Jhon    1000
1 2020-01-02   Bread   Mat    1000
2 2020-01-03   Bread  Jhon    2000
3 2020-01-04   Bread  Bill    2000
4 2020-01-05   Water  Jhon    1000
```

For example, at the end of 2020-01-03 John should have 2000€ of Bread(1000-2000+3000).
Is there any way that i can achieve this result. I have tried countless ways of group by but nothing worked as intended.

Comment: Can you post the expected output, i.e. how does the data look for all users as a whole?

Comment: Can you be more precise? What's your expected output?

Comment: Your dataframe doesn't match your expected output in your description. Perhaps you have your products mixed up?

Comment: Btw, your `day` column should be like this:
`'day': [pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01"), pd.to_datetime("2020-01-02"), pd.to_datetime("2020-01-03"), pd.to_datetime("2020-01-04"), pd.to_datetime("2020-01-05")]`
You have to use pd.to_datetime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically using accounting principles,  turn it into a ledger of buy and sell transactions.  Then `cumsum()` is straight forward.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,1,1), dt.date(2020,1,5)), 
                   'Product': ['Bread', 'Water', 'Bread', 'Bread', 'Water'], 
                   'Buyer': ['John', 'Mat', 'John', 'Bill', 'John'], 
                   'Seller': ['Mat', 'John', 'Bill', 'John', 'Bill'], 
                   'Volume':[1000,2000,3000,2000,1000]
                  })

# transform to effectively a double entry ledger
dfde = pd.concat([df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c!="Buyer"]]
           .rename(columns={"Seller":"Account"})
                  .assign(Volume=lambda dfa: dfa["Volume"]*-1, Ind="S")
          ,df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c!="Seller"]]
           .rename(columns={"Buyer":"Account"})
           .assign( Ind="B")
          ]).sort_values(["day","Product","Account"]).assign(Holding=dfde.groupby(["Product","Account"]).cumsum())
```

### output

```
       day Product Account  Volume Ind  Holding
2020-01-01   Bread    John    1000   B     1000
2020-01-01   Bread     Mat   -1000   S    -1000
2020-01-02   Water    John   -2000   S    -2000
2020-01-02   Water     Mat    2000   B     2000
2020-01-03   Bread    Bill   -3000   S    -3000
2020-01-03   Bread    John    3000   B     4000
2020-01-04   Bread    Bill    2000   B    -1000
2020-01-04   Bread    John   -2000   S     2000
2020-01-05   Water    Bill   -1000   S    -1000
2020-01-05   Water    John    1000   B    -1000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. ¿How should i modify the code if I want to calculate the holding of the "Account" considering the two previous periods (in this case the previous two days)?

Comment: given it's now effectively a double entry ledger,  you can filter the ledger (on dates that you are interested in) then do calculations.  standard approaches to data management,  project, filter, calculate

Comment: Yes, that is what i was doing but my intention is to achieve the same output that you posted but for each day only consider "x previous periods". For example, If we only consider the previous day the John's Bread Holding on 2020-01-04 should be 1000 (3000-2000) not considering 2020-01-01 bread adquisition.